# Device Type Text for iPhone 4S and iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios

what will be the output of the following code:

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
NSLog(@"Device Type: %@", deviceType);
```

in iPhone 4, it will print "iPhone" but in iPhone 4S or iPhone 5 what will be the output? I don't have iPhone 4S or 5 device. But I need to know it for implementing calling feature in all the versions of iPhones.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in iPhone 4, it will print "iPhone" but in iPhone 4S or iPhone 5 what will be the output?

Also "iPhone".

([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html).)

Comment: funny answer nice 1 :) @H2CO3

Comment: OP really made you work hard on this one didn't he! Regardless, correct +1.

Comment: in the documentation where it says? are you sure it will print iPhone in iPhone 5 also ?

Comment: @sumon It will indeed print "iPhone".

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle I had a hard time figuring it out. Took me almost a minute ;-)

Answer (score 1):

UIDevice isnt helpful use

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

- (NSString *)deviceModel
{
    NSString *deviceModel = nil;
    char buffer[32];
    size_t length = sizeof(buffer);
    if (sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &buffer, &length, NULL, 0) == 0) {
        deviceModel = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:buffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    }
    return [deviceModel autorelease];
}
```

I also dont know the constant for the 5 but I *know* they are unique:

```
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad-3G (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad-3G (4G)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad-3G (4G)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
```

Phone 5 GSM - iPhone5,1

iPhone 5 CDMA - iPhone5,2

iPod 5 - iPod5,1

Info taken from the iOS file names. Please check http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/19/ios-6-ipsw-direct-download-links/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to differentiate between iPhone4/4S & iPhone5, you should check the screen size, not the device model.

Comment: This isn't as good of a solution. If you're trying to tell the difference between an iPhone 4S and an iPhone 5 this will work, but, using screen size/scale you are unable to detect iPad Mini vs. iPad 2. Detecting machine ID as explained in @Daij-Djan's answer is the way to go.